# Limit of Exponential Sum

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $x_1,\dots, \in \mathbb{R}$, $y>0$, and define:
$$
f(\lambda)\triangleq \frac1{\lambda} \ln\left(
\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda x_i}
\right).
$$
What is $\lim_{\lambda \to 0} f(\lambda)$ and $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} f(\lambda)$?

It seems easy but I really can't manage it...

Comment: The first thing I would do is use the continuity of $\ln$ and its exponential properties...so 
$\lim_{\lambda \to \star}f(\lambda)=
\ln(
\lim_{\lambda \to \star}  \left(\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(\lambda x_i)}\right)^{\lambda}
)
.
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hôpital's rule,$$\lim_{\lambda\to0}f(\lambda)=\lim_{\lambda\to0}\frac{\frac1n\sum_ix_ie^{\lambda x_i}}{\frac1n\sum_ie^{\lambda x_i}}=\bar{x}.$$By the same technique,$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}f(\lambda)=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n\sum_ix_ie^{\lambda x_i}}{\frac1n\sum_ie^{\lambda x_i}}=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n\sum_ix_ie^{-\lambda(x_\max-x_i)}}{\frac1n\sum_ie^{-\lambda(x_\max-x_i)}}=x_\max.$$